# Как Drive может позволить нам загружать папки с файлами и вложенными папками, если современные браузеры обрабатывают файлы только по одному?

Tags: django, backend, google-drive

Как Google Drive позволяет загружать папки с файлами и вложенными папками? Потому что я пытался воссоздать то же самое в своем веб-приложении, и кажется, что последние браузеры не воспринимают их как папки, а рассматривают файлы внутри по одному. Чтобы проверить это, я попробовал использовать dropzone.js.

Во front-end я поместил dropzone.js (он работает в моем веб-приложении, но не в SO, извините за ошибки, я не fullstack-программист):

```js
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#demo-upload', {
  previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
  parallelUploads: 2,
  thumbnailHeight: 120,
  thumbnailWidth: 120,
  maxFilesize: 3,
  filesizeBase: 1000,
  thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
    if (file.previewElement) {
      file.previewElement.classList.remove("dz-file-preview");
      var images = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-thumbnail]");
      for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var thumbnailElement = images[i];
        thumbnailElement.alt = file.name;
        thumbnailElement.src = dataUrl;
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-image-preview");
      }, 1);
    }
  }

});


// Now fake the file upload, since GitHub does not handle file uploads
// and returns a 404

var minSteps = 6,
  maxSteps = 60,
  timeBetweenSteps = 100,
  bytesPerStep = 100000;

dropzone.uploadFiles = function(files) {
  var self = this;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    var file = files[i];
    totalSteps = Math.round(Math.min(maxSteps, Math.max(minSteps, file.size / bytesPerStep)));

    for (var step = 0; step < totalSteps; step++) {
      var duration = timeBetweenSteps * (step + 1);
      setTimeout(function(file, totalSteps, step) {
        return function() {
          file.upload = {
            progress: 100 * (step + 1) / totalSteps,
            total: file.size,
            bytesSent: (step + 1) * file.size / totalSteps
          };

          self.emit('uploadprogress', file, file.upload.progress, file.upload.bytesSent);
          if (file.upload.progress == 100) {
            file.status = Dropzone.SUCCESS;
            self.emit("success", file, 'success', null);
            self.emit("complete", file);
            self.processQueue();
            //document.getElementsByClassName("dz-success-mark").style.opacity = "1";
          }
        };
      }(file, totalSteps, step), duration);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(243, 244, 245);
  height: 100%;
  color: rgb(100, 108, 127);
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-family: Roboto, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropzone {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed rgb(0, 135, 247);
  border-image: none;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>DropzoneJS File Upload Demo</h1>
<SECTION>
  <DIV id="dropzone">
    <FORM class="dropzone needsclick" id="demo-upload" action="/upload">
      <DIV class="dz-message needsclick">
        Drop files here or click to upload.
        <BR>
        <SPAN class="note needsclick">(This is just a demo dropzone. Selected 
        files are <STRONG>not</STRONG> actually uploaded.)</SPAN>
      </DIV>
    </FORM>
  </DIV>
</SECTION>
```

А в бэкенде я пытаюсь узнать, когда это папка или файл с помощью `is_folder()`.

```
def is_folder(file):
    # Sécurisez le nom du fichier
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    # Créez un chemin complet vers le fichier temporaire
    file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)

    # Vérifiez si le fichier est un dossier
    return os.path.isdir(file_path)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    user_id = session.get('user_id')
    summaries = get_existant_summaries(user_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_id:
            # check if the post request has the file part
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                flash('No file part')
                return redirect(request.url)
            file = request.files['file']
            print("request.files: ", request.files)
            if is_folder(file):
                print("YOUPI")
            else:
                print("is_folder(file): ", is_folder(file))
```

После загрузки папки она работает как серия архивов:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2023 17:16:48] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2023 17:16:48] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
request.files:  ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: 'Data_engineer.pdf' ('application/pdf')>)])
request.files:  ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: 'Data_Scientist.pdf' ('application/pdf')>)])
is_folder(file):  False
is_folder(file):  False
```